# IF statement fade in text css

Tags: html, css, animation

I am trying to create the equivalent of an IF statement in CSS. I have a small circle rotating around a larger circle. When the smaller circle reaches each of the points i want to fade in text in the centre.

Not sure if it's possible using CSS to say, when the small circle reaches x/y point then activate fade in text animation.

[image]

```
@keyframes clockwiseRotate {
    from {
        transform: rotate(0deg)
    }

    to {
        transform: rotate(360deg)
    }
}

@keyframes counterClockwiseRotate {
    from {
        transform: rotate(0deg)
    }

    to {
        transform: rotate(-360deg)
    }
}

i {
    animation: counterClockwiseRotate 25s linear infinite
}


body {
    background-color: #022052;
}

.circle1{
    border: 1px solid #0462FF;
    width: 350px;
    height: 350px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 24.3%;
    top: 30px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.link{
    color:#fff;
    width:20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius:50%;
    border:1px solid #444;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    line-height:33px;
}

.fb{
    background:#0462FF;
    border-color:#0462FF;
    transform:translate(40px,40px);
}

.cp{
    background:#0462FF;
    border-color:#0462FF;
    transform:translate(285px,40px);
}

.li{
    background:#0462FF;
    border-color:#0462FF;
    transform:translate(300px,270px);
}

.tw{
    background:#0462FF;
    border-color:#0462FF;
    transform:translate(25px,270px);
}

.an{
    background:#0462FF;
    border-color:#0462FF;
    transform:translate(25px,270px);
}

.circle2{
    border: 1px solid #0462FF;
    width: 350px;
    height: 350px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 24.3%;
    top: 30px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    animation: clockwiseRotate 25s linear infinite;
}
```

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Rotating circle</title>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" 
rel="stylesheet">

<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' 

href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/css/
materialize.min.css'>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">


</head>

<body>

<ul class="circle2">

<li class="link an"><i class="an an-new"></i></li>


</ul>

<ul class="circle1">



<li class="link fb"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></li>
        <li class="link tw"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></li>
        <li class="link li"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></li>
        <li class="link cp"><i class="fa fa-codepen"></i></li>


    </ul>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you can coordinate, since you control the time and delay

Comment: Could you elaborate on this? Are you saying when the circle has reached co-ordinates activate fade in text?

Comment: i meant you can coordinate --> you know the animation so you know when it will reach [after how many seconds] so you can create the fade animation based on this

Comment: Javascript would be an easier way to implement this

Comment: Just do the math. Four coordination points, so divide the time it takes to complete one rotation by four. That's the base for whatever you want to happen at each point.

Comment: @YvetteColomb I disagree. Easily possible in CSS.

Comment: Please post your HTML as well.

Comment: @BramVanroy just added html. If it's advised to solve this with javascript i'll look into that.

Comment: You don't seem to have added enough HTML for us to reproduce your problem (demo of current code: https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/onsxcbaL/1/); can you take a look at the "[mcve]" guidelines and post enough code that we can see where you're at, without having to create a hypothetical demonstration? That way our answers are more specifically useful for you, and provide better illustrations of alternate approaches for future visitors to this question.

Comment: @DavidThomas I may have accidentally missed a line out. What is now showing correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example of how you can accomplish fading text based on your parameters. Given that you have only four points, it's quite easy to calculate. I used percentages with opacity in my example.

```css
@keyframes clockwiseRotate {
    from {
        transform: rotate(0deg)
    }

    to {
        transform: rotate(360deg)
    }
}

@keyframes counterClockwiseRotate {
    from {
        transform: rotate(0deg)
    }

    to {
        transform: rotate(-360deg)
    }
}

i {
    animation: counterClockwiseRotate 25s linear infinite
}


body {
    background-color: #022052;
}

.circle1{
    border: 1px solid #0462FF;
    width: 350px;
    height: 350px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 24.3%;
    top: 30px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.link{
    color:#fff;
    width:20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius:50%;
    border:1px solid #444;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    line-height:33px;
}

.fb{
    background:#0462FF;
    border-color:#0462FF;
    transform:translate(40px,40px);
}

.cp{
    background:#0462FF;
    border-color:#0462FF;
    transform:translate(285px,40px);
}

.li{
    background:#0462FF;
    border-color:#0462FF;
    transform:translate(300px,270px);
}

.tw{
    background:#0462FF;
    border-color:#0462FF;
    transform:translate(25px,270px);
}

.an{
    background:#0462FF;
    border-color:#0462FF;
    transform:translate(25px,270px);
}

.circle2{
    border: 1px solid #0462FF;
    width: 350px;
    height: 350px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 24.3%;
    top: 30px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    animation: clockwiseRotate 25s linear infinite;
}
.circle3 {
    width: 350px;
    height: 350px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 24.3%;
    top: 30px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.circle3 > li {
    width: 350px;
    height: 350px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    color: #FFF;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    opacity: 0;
}
.circle3 > li.facebook {
  animation: fadeFacebook 25s linear infinite;
}
.circle3 > li.twitter {
  animation: fadeTwitter 25s linear infinite;
}
.circle3 > li.linkedin {
  animation: fadeLinkedin 25s linear infinite;
}
.circle3 > li.codepen {
  animation: fadeCodepen 25s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes fadeTwitter {
  0%, 20% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  25%, 95% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes fadeFacebook {
  0%, 20% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  25%, 45% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes fadeCodepen {
  0%, 45% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50%, 70% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  75% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes fadeLinkedin {
  0%, 70% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  75%, 95% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/css/materialize.min.css'>

<ul class="circle2">
  <li class="link an"><i class="an an-new"></i></li>
</ul>

<ul class="circle1">
  <li class="link fb"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></li>
  <li class="link tw"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></li>
  <li class="link li"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></li>
  <li class="link cp"><i class="fa fa-codepen"></i></li>
</ul>

<ul class="circle3">
  <li class="text facebook">Facebook</li>
  <li class="text twitter">Twitter</li>
  <li class="text linkedin">Linkedin</li>
  <li class="text codepen">Codepen</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: awesome thanks for this, stupid question - but when i copy and paste the code into new files it doesn't seem to work?

Comment: Sure thing. It’s hard to tell without seeing all of the code. It works in the example snippet it could be that you’ve missed copying all of the example code or that you have one or more of the same classes in your files and/or competing CSS somewhere, etc, etc.

Comment: thanks got it working, realised the stylesheet wasn't linked. Another question - If i wanted to change the duration of animation. e.g - linkedin wording to show after 7 seconds and then codepen 4 seconds later how would that work? I can see in the code that each word has 'fadeTwitter 25s' but it's not 25 seconds?

Comment: It's important to note that there's many different ways to accomplish your initial question. In my approach, I took advantage of the fact that four points simply translate to 0%, 25%, 50%, and 75% and I used 5% for transition time. During the 25s animation, each element is visible for (25 / 4)s. You could refactor everything to utilize animation delays on the text if that makes it easier but I just chose to run everything on the same duration. I recommend reading up on [animations and keyframes](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp).

Answer (score 0):

I have created a example for you based on `transition` timings...You will need to make only two `animation`, one for the rotation of the circle `rotate` and second for the text fade `fade`...You will also need to play with some `animation-delay`...

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.circle {
  font: 13px Verdana;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #022052;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 30px auto 0;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px #022052;
}

.circle i {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #0e61fb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.circle i.fa-facebook {
  left: calc(90%);
  top: calc(10%);
}

.circle i.fa-twitter {
  left: calc(90%);
  top: calc(90%);
}

.circle i.fa-linkedin {
  left: calc(10%);
  top: calc(90%);
}

.circle i.fa-codepen {
  left: calc(10%);
  top: calc(10%);
}

.pin,
.text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.pin {
  animation: rotate 8s linear infinite;
}

.pin:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #0e61fb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
}

@keyframes rotate {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes fade {
  0%,
  12.5% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  12.6%,
  37.5% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  37.6%,
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.text p {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  opacity: 0;
  animation: fade 8s linear infinite;
  color: #fff;
}

.text p:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.text p:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 2s;
}

.text p:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 4s;
}

.text p:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 6s;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="circle">
  <div class="pin"></div>
  <div class="text">
    <p>Facebook</p>
    <p>Twitter</p>
    <p>Linkedin</p>
    <p>Codepen</p>
  </div>
  <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-codepen"></i>
</div>
```